# How to print numeric loop inside every item in list using kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How to print  numeric loop inside every item in list using kotlin

After print First item in the list

Print numbers from 1 to 10
Then print seconded item in the list then print numbers from 1 to 10.   etc.,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please [edit] your question to include your own effort?

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote I think that would be the answer:

```
    fun main()
{
    val list = listOf("a", "b", "c")

    for (x in 1..list.size)
    {
        for (y in 1..10)
        {
            println(y)
        }
        println(list[x - 1])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example is using a `List<String>` as list of items since you haven't narrowed that down to a specific datatype in your question. However, it shows how to print the every item followed by the numbers from 1 to 10:

```kotlin
fun main () {
    // create an example list of items (Strings here)
    val list = listOf("first item", "second item", "third item", "fourth item")
    // for each item in that list
    for (item in list) {
        // print that item
        println(item)
        // and for each number from 1 to 10
        for (i in 1..10) {
            // print that number
            println(i)
        }
    }
}
```

The (ugly) output of this code is

```
first item
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
second item
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
third item
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
fourth item
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```